# h2o randomForest variable importance

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix, h2o

I am using h2o package to create randomForest regression model. I have some problems with the variables importance. The model I am creating is here. Everything works fine.

Some of the variables are numeric, but some are categorical.

```
RandomForest <- h2o.randomForest(x = c("Year",  "Month", "Day", "Time", "Show", "Gen",
                                   "D", "Lead"), y = "Ratio", data = data.hex, importance=T, stat.type = "GINI",
                             ntree = 50, depth = 50, nodesize = 5, oobee = T, classification = FALSE, type = "BigData")
```

However, when I want to see the variable importance, the output looks like this.

```
Classification: FALSE
Number of trees: 50
Tree statistics:
        Min.  Max.    Mean.
Depth     30    40    33.26
Leaves 20627 21450 21130.24


Variable importance:
                        Year    Month      Day     Time  Show   Gen           D   Lead
Relative importance 20536.64 77821.76 26742.55 67476.75 283447.3 60651.24   87440.38 3658.625
Standard Deviation        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
Z-Scores                  NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA

Overall Mean-squared Error:
```

What I would like to know is:
 1) Why there could be NA values.
 2) What does actually Relative importance mean. Shouldn't it be between 1 and 100?
 3) Why there is no confusion matrix in the output?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your outcome (`y`) variable continuous? The output states `Classification: FALSE`. A confusion matrix applies only to categorical outcome variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend downloading the latest version of H20-3. This may solve the problem of you getting a NA value for your standard deviation. 
Relative importance quantifies the contributions of a specific predicator against those made by other individual predictors in predicting the response variable.  The number that you might be thinking of that needs to be between 1 and 100 is the scaled importance.
Lastly, the reason you are not getting a confusion matrix in your output is that you have a regression model rather than a classification model. Confusion matrices are only produced for classification models.

You can run a random forest example in R by running the following commands:

```
library(h2o)
conn <- h2o.init()
demo(h2o.randomForest)
```

You can then see your confusion matrix/relative and scaled importance table by doing the following:

```
> h2o.confusionMatrix(iris.rf)
Confusion Matrix - (vertical: actual; across: predicted):
                Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica  Error      Rate
Iris-setosa       50.000000        0.000000       0.000000 0.0000 =  0 / 50
Iris-versicolor    0.000000       47.000000       3.000000 0.0600 =  3 / 50
Iris-virginica     0.000000        6.000000      44.000000 0.1200 =  6 / 50
Totals            50.000000       53.000000      47.000000 0.0600 = 9 / 150
> h2o.varimp(iris.rf)
Variable Importances:
   variable relative_importance scaled_importance percentage
1 petal_len         1926.421509          1.000000   0.445738
2 petal_wid         1756.277710          0.911679   0.406370
3 sepal_len          493.782562          0.256321   0.114252
4 sepal_wid          145.390717          0.075472   0.033641
```

Thanks and hope this helps!

Comment: What does relative importance tell you? Does a higher value mean that that variable is the most contributing in predicting the target variable with respect to other variables? or is it the vice-versa? So, in your example, relative importance id higher for petal_len, does it mean it is the most important?